# Excel: sum a number for every colum that contains a number

Tags: excel

I have a basic excel spreadsheet like this:

`A           B           C          D       etc..
 1           1           0          0     etc..
 0           0           1          1     etc..
 0           0           1          1     etc..`

I would like to SUM 100 for every cell that contains 1 in one Cell and to SUM 100 por every cell that contains 0 in other cell.. How can i do this?

I hope you understand my question, english its not my first language.

Comment: What is SUM 100? `=SUM(100)` or `=SUM100()`? You need to clarify.

Comment: you question is not clear. can you please give with some example?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the answers might be

```
=COUNTIF(A1:D10,1)*100
```

and

```
=COUNTIF(A1:D10,0)*100
```

(change the ranges as necessary)

Comment: `=SUM(COUNITIF(A1:D10,{1,0}))*100`

Comment: I think OP wants the two answers in separate cells (although not clear). I'm assuming that SUM means ADD (añadir) ?

Comment: But you could also do =COUNTIF(A1:D10,{1,0})*100 as an array formula that could be expanded across two cells...